# Modem GPRS indicates be connected but doesn't receive or send any data

Tags: tcp, embedded, gsm, at-command, gprs

I'm implementing an application that sends data to a server and also receives. So, to always be able to receive data, I choosed keep it always connected. To get this, I use GL865 Telit modem into the client. It's configured using TCP.

The problem I have is that sometimes the modem socket status indicates that it is connected, also, when I send data it says that is OK but nothing is arriving on server and, when I send data from server to client, it doesn't receive too.

I'm testing sending data every 1 second. Many minutes after it begins to loose data, it becomes to result error at sending data and later indicates that there isn't a connection with gprs.

Comment: Have you used something like [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to see just what's going on with your communication?

Comment: No, not yet but I'll do it now...thanks for suggestion.

Comment: Hi fellow, I've already installed and executed the wireshark and what I see is that nothing is arriving to the connection after some bytes. Also, something I've noted is that it's almost all times 90 bytes, some times 96, sent, when I'm sending test msgs of 6 bytes every second. That is, after 15 maybe 16 seconds it stops to send.

Comment: I changed the period between msgs to for 2 by 2 seconds. Also changed the size of the packet sent from 6 to 3 bytes. After these changes it continues to send only 16 times showing that this is not the time or the number of bytes but the maximum number of packets per connection.

Comment: What _exactly_ is this "do result error"?

Comment: Sorry, it is "to result error". That means that trying to send data, Telit returns error.

Comment: If nothing your sending gets to the server and nothing the server sends is received by the client perhaps you just have a configuration issue. This is especially likely if you are seeing data going out over wireshark. If you're getting an error message from your modem ("Telit returns error") It's possible the data packets are not formatted correctly, at least not in a way your modem is happy with. You're going to have to post more details for anyone to be able to help. For example, the part of your code responsible for senging data, the wireshark log, and **exact** error message.

Comment: Okuma, I tested and I am able to send 16 packets. After it sends 16 packets it fails for a period and later reconect. It doesn't seems a configuration error...

Comment: Do you use **USB** or **serial** connection?  Is the failure during *PPP* negotiation, or you have an IP address and then loss the connection?  What **baud rate** are you running at if serial and what hardware/driver are you using?  Are you using **CMUX** on serial?  Are you observing the *flow control* signals?

Comment: Hi Artless Noise, I'm using serial. Apparently, I've lost the connection. I've found that every 16 packets, sending or receiving, I have to connect again. I suspect that this is a action of the telephonic operator...

Comment: unsure if this is still somewhere active. 
16B is a typical buffer size. Is it possible that the serial UART's RTS/CTS pair flags busy after 16B because nothing gets read (and the buffer is full)?